# "___" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables

Any tips on how to make these variables usable outside the if statements they are defined in?

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num1 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num2 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num3 = kb.nextDouble();

    if (num1>num2){
        if (num1>num3){
            double hypo = num1;
            double side1 = num2;
            double side2 = num3;
        }else{
            double hypo = num3;
            double side1 = num1;
            double side2 = num2; }
    }else if (num2>num3){
        double hypo = num2;
        double side1 = num1;
        double side2 = num3; }

    if ((hypo*hypo)-((side1*side1)+(side2*side2)) == 0){

    }
```

I also tried doing it this way:

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num1 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num2 = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter a length of a side of a triangle: ");
    double num3 = kb.nextDouble();
    final double hypo;
    final double side1;
    final double side2;

    if (num1>num2){
        if (num1>num3){
            hypo = num1;
            side1 = num2;
            side2 = num3;
        }else{
            hypo = num3;
            side1 = num1;
            side2 = num2; }
    }else if (num2>num3){
        hypo = num2;
        side1 = num1;
        side2 = num3; }

    if ((hypo*hypo)-((side1*side1)+(side2*side2)) == 0){

    }
```

I got help with this yesterday on the website, but didn't understand how that solution was obtained. An explanation would be great

Comment: You might check out a few tutorials about the language online. This one describes [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Move the declaration up so the variables still have scope,

```
double hypo = num3;
double side1 = num2;
double side2 = num1; 
if (num1 > num2){
  if (num1 > num3){
    hypo = num1;
    side1 = num2;
    side2 = num3;
  } else {
    hypo = num3;
    side1 = num1;
    side2 = num2;
  }
} else if (num2 > num3) {
  hypo = num2;
  side1 = num1;
  side2 = num3; 
}
```